# How to have an existing table column in the database for a user when an account is created in Laravel 5

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I have created a very simple application where a user is able to update an 'amount' that is stored in the database. Everything is working properly but my problem is right now a user has to create an instance in the database and then they are able to update the existing instances 'amount' column in the database.

I would like to have it so that the 'amount' field already exists and is connected to that specific user when they create an account. Instead of the user having to create an instance for the 'amount' and then they are able to update it.

Also I am using a 'Laravel Collective' for "Forms & HTML" to display in the index.php

I was hoping if someone can point me in the right direction to get this started as I am a bit clueless on how the process will work. Where do I start?

Here is my the button and form in my index.blade.php

```
            {{--  This is to update the amount  --}}
            @if(count($amounts) > 0)
            @foreach($amounts as $total)
            {!! Form::open(['action' => ['CurrencyBlocksController@update', $total->id], 'method' => 'POST', 'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']) !!}
                <div class="form-group">
                    <h3>{{Form::label('amount', 'Amount:')}}</h3>
                    {{Form::text('amount', $total->amount, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Title'])}}
                </div>
                {{Form::hidden('_method', 'PUT')}}
                {{Form::submit('Submit', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary'])}}    
            {!! Form::close() !!}
            @endforeach
            @endif
```

How I have my web route setup:

```
Route::resource('currency_blocks', 'CurrencyBlocksController');
Auth::routes();
```

Here is a snapshot of the table in the database:

[image]

Here is the Controller [ only important is the index() & update() function ]:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use App\User;
use App\CurrencyBlock;

class CurrencyBlocksController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $user_id = auth()->user()->id;
        $user = User::find($user_id);
        $amounts = CurrencyBlock::find('amount');
        return view('blocks.index')->with('amounts', $user->amounts);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'amount' => 'required'
        ]);

        // Update Post
        $total = CurrencyBlock::find($id);
        $total->amount = $request->input('amount');
        $total->user_id = auth()->user()->id;
        $total->save();

        //return redirect('/currency_blocks/{{$amount->id}}/edit')->with('amount', $amount)->with('success', 'Post Updated');
        return redirect('/currency_blocks')->with('success', 'Amount Updated');
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

The CurrencyBlock:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class CurrencyBlock extends Model
{
    // Table Name
    protected $table = 'currency_blocks';

    // Primary Key
    public $primaryKey = 'id';

    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}
```

Comment: FYI the way this is written anyone could update anyone's currency block as long as they provide the currency ID and the amount

Comment: It is not very clear what you need to change. You've written that *when they create an account.* Where is that fragment of code? so you can add there whatever you want

Comment: need to be a lil bit more right to the point!

Comment: Hello, sorry that's what I was expecting. I will work on it a bit more and see if I can get you guys the write info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create the entry when the user is created like this

```
$user = User::create($data); 
$user->currency()->create(here you put ur empty entry of currency );
```

And don't forget to add currency relationship in the User model;

```
public function currency () {return $this->has one(User::class,'user_id');}
```

Comment: Thanks @Bm2ilabs for pointing me in the right direction. I got it working, much appreciated.

Comment: I'm glad I could help ;)